Why am I getting downvoted in this?
(Can stardust give rise to new stars?)
I don't get what's wrong in my answer and it's perfectly logical. If someone feels a lack of effort, I would like to say that there's no more to write. That would be out of context, even if someone wrote. Moreover, I feel the answer completely logical.
Please tell me your views.

I imagine you are getting down votes because your second paragraph:

Also, universe is explosively expanding. It's almost impossible that the star remains will come close enough to form new stars. (Although, they can't if it only has heavier elements). So, no, stardust can't give rise to new stars.

is not correct.  Stellar remains are, in fact, a significant contributor to the composition of new stars.  They make up a small but very important part of the mass.  (Moreover, while the universe is expanding on extragalactic scales, the interiors of galaxies, where stars are located, are not expanding.)
A wrong answer is probably the best reason to down vote something.  So there is no reason to see anything inappropriate going on here.
